# Order of growth of triple for loop

Tags: time-complexity

I'm practising algorithm complexity and I came across this code online but I cannot figure out the order of growth for it. Any ideas?

```
    int counter= 0;
    for (int i = 0; i*i < N; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j*j < 4*N; j++)
    for (int k = 0; k < N*N; k++)
    counter++;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take it one step (or loop in this case) at a time:

1. The first loop increments `i` as long its square is lower than `N`, so this must be `O(sqrt N)`, because `int(sqrt(N))` or `int(sqrt(N)) - 1` is the largest integer value whose square is lower than `N`;
2. The same holds for the second loop. We can ignore the `4` because it is a constant, and we do not care about those when dealing with big-oh notation. So the first two loops together are `O(sqrt N)*O(sqrt N) = O(sqrt(N)^2) = O(N)`. You can multiply the complexities because the loops are nested, so the second loop will fully execute for each iteration of the first;
3. The third loop is obviously `O(N^2)`, because `k` goes up to the square of `N`.

So the whole thing has to be `O(N) * O(N^2) = O(N^3)`. You can usually solve problems like this by figuring out the complexity of the first loop, then the second, then the first two and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. it does make more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Sqrt n x 2 Sqrt n x n ^ 2

Which gives:

O n^3

Explanation:

For the first loop, square root both sides of the equation

i^2 = n

For the second loop, square root both sides of the equation

j^2 = 4n^2

The third loop is straight forward.

Comment: @JVTura - I notice that you haven't accepted an answer to any of your questions. If an answer has helped you, please tick the green check mark to the left of it in order to mark it as accepted.